# DirectX11: Height based texture blending

Tags: c++, directx, texture-mapping, direct3d11

I currently have 3 textures being blended using a slope amount, in my terrain project.  I do this by sampling each texture, determining the slope amount and setting the texture colour based on a lerp between two textures.  This is the snippet of this from my pixel shader:

```
static const float TEX_LOW_BOUND    = 0.4f;
static const float TEX_HIGH_BOUND   = 0.7f; 

...    

float4 texColour;
float4 lowColour = lowerTex.Sample(SWrap, pin.Tex);
float4 midColour = middleTex.Sample(SWrap, pin.Tex);
float4 hiColour  = upperTex.Sample(SWrap, pin.Tex);
float slope      = 1.0f - pin.Normal.y;

if (slope < TEX_LOW_BOUND)
{
    texColour = lerp(lowColour, midColour, slope / TEX_LOW_BOUND);
}
else if (slope >= TEX_LOW_BOUND && slope < TEX_HIGH_BOUND)
{
    texColour = lerp(midColour, hiColour, (slope - TEX_LOW_BOUND) * (1.0f / (TEX_HIGH_BOUND - TEX_LOW_BOUND)));
}
else if (slope >= TEX_HIGH_BOUND)
{
    texColour = hiColour;
}
```

I want to add a final snow texture, to apply above a certain height.  I get the height value in my vertex shader by using:

```
vout.WHeight = mul(vin.Pos, worldMatrix).y;
```

I can then just set the texture colour to the snow above a certain height using this in my pixel shader:

```
if (pin.WHeight > 35.0f)
{
    texColour = snowTex.Sample(SWrap, pin.Tex);
}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: Snow above a certain height]

How can I blend the edge of the snow with the other textures so that the edge isn't so harsh. Bearing in mind the other textures may have already been lerped, and i'd like to maintain the texture colour.

Thank you for your time

Comment: The same way you did with slope.

Comment: How exactly do I integrate the height value with the linear interpolation based on the slope.  I just want to blend the edge of the snow, so it fades the further down the hill it goes.

Comment: Take final color after slope part (let's call it "grass"), take snow color.  Calculate your interpolation coefficient as a function of height (ex: absolute snow: heights 200 and higher, snow color amount 100%; absolute grass: height below 150, snow color amount 0%). Do lerp (or whatever blending function you like).

Answer (score 1):

You can do basically the same thing you just did when adding in the color for the snow caps, but what you would need here is a ranged input to determine if it is close to the edge. There are several approaches to doing this. One method could be to blend the pixel values with color addition or subtraction then normalize between the range of color value. The other would be to apply multiple texture blending. As you stated in your condition above `if (pin.WHeight > 35.0f)`
 we know that 35.0f is the maximum height value before you start to apply the snow texture. Depending on your desired results your ranged based input might be something like: `if ( height > 34.8f && height < 35.2f ) { apply texture blending or color blending; }`.

The other method would be to use an alpha value with transparency fading layer over top of the original layer using the same ranged input to produce the desired output.

The only thing with this type of approach or algorithm is that it may not appear to look as realistic as you would like. This is because all the snow caps will have exactly the same height value creating an unrealistic perimeter.

A suggestion which would be close to your original approach may work out better. When applying the texture or color to your snow caps you could have an nondeterministic algorithm that would randomly select specific heights within a min range to apply the texture - texture blending, then anything over a specific height above that would then smooth out to being pure white. This way each mountain top would have a white cap, but not all of the heights would be the same at the lower bounds.